# Without Converting to a String, How Many Digits Does a Fixnum Have?

Tags: ruby, integer, ruby-1.9, fixnum

I want find the `length` of a [`Fixnum`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Fixnum.html), `num`, without converting it into a `String`.

In other words, how many digits are in `num` without calling the `.to_s()` method:

```ruby
num.to_s.length
```

Comment: What is the "length of a `Fixnum`"? In what representation?

Comment: @JörgWMittag: How many digits are in it.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
puts Math.log10(1234).to_i + 1 # => 4
```

You could add it to Fixnum like this:

```
class Fixnum
  def num_digits
    Math.log10(self).to_i + 1
  end
end

puts 1234.num_digits # => 4
```

Comment: Every time I profile something, I get a surprise.  In MRI 1.9.3, `n.to_s.length` is faster for any integer represented by a Fixnum.  A _lot_ faster: On my box, `n.to_s.length` takes somewhere between a third and half the time of the logarithm method, depending upon the length of the number.  If the number has to be represented a Bignum, then the logarithm method starts winning.  Both methods are very fast, though, at around .6 milliseconds (for the logarithm method), and between 0.2 and 0.3 milliseconds (for the string method).

Comment: @WayneConrad: Sounds like `Math.log10` must have a rather inefficient implementation. I just tried a simple method which walks over a table of all the powers of 10 which fit in 32/64 bits, and does a `>=` comparison for each one -- it was a touch faster than `Math.log10`, but still slower than `to_s`. It could be made faster by "unrolling" a binary search of the same table, just like unrolling a loop (then the table wouldn't be needed any more -- the same numbers would be hard-coded into a series of conditionals).

Comment: @sawa: yes, I noticed. Calling `.abs` resulted in a warning (when run with `ruby -w`) which I did not understood nor cared for. I figured an error was still better then a wrong result from the `to_s.size` idea.

Comment: what about the negative integers ?

Comment: Warning: This breaks with 0 as well.

Comment: The method size works well with fixnum objects. 10.size, fixnum.size.

Comment: @WayneConrad your comment is outdated, [look at my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866874/2235594) below

Answer (score 16):

Ruby 2.4 has an [Integer#digits](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-digits) method, which return an Array containing the digits.

```
num = 123456
num.digits
# => [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1] 
num.digits.count
# => 6
```

**EDIT:**

To handle negative numbers (thanks @MatzFan), use the absolute value. [Integer#abs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-abs)

```
-123456.abs.digits
# => [6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: ..if it is a positive Integer, otherwise `Math::DomainError`. So much more Ruby though

Comment: check [my benchmarks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48866874/2235594) why you should *not* use `.digits` for large scale use cases

Answer (score 10):

Sidenote for **Ruby 2.4+**

I ran some benchmarks on the different solutions, and `Math.log10(x).to_i + 1` is actually *a lot faster* than `x.to_s.length`. The [comment from @Wayne Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005524/how-do-i-determine-the-length-of-a-fixnum-in-ruby/14005668#comments-14005668) is out of date. The [new solution with `digits.count`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41334337/2235594) is trailing far behind, especially with larger numbers:

```
with_10_digits = 2_040_240_420

print Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { Math.log10(with_10_digits).to_i + 1 } }
# => 0.100000   0.000000   0.100000 (  0.109846)
print Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { with_10_digits.to_s.length } }
# => 0.360000   0.000000   0.360000 (  0.362604)
print Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { with_10_digits.digits.count } }
# => 0.690000   0.020000   0.710000 (  0.717554)

with_42_digits = 750_325_442_042_020_572_057_420_745_037_450_237_570_322

print Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { Math.log10(with_42_digits).to_i + 1 } }
# => 0.140000   0.000000   0.140000 (  0.142757)
print Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { with_42_digits.to_s.length } }
# => 1.180000   0.000000   1.180000 (  1.186603)
print Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times { with_42_digits.digits.count } }
# => 8.480000   0.040000   8.520000 (  8.577174)
```

Comment: Another data point: Using Ruby 3.0, for a 208987640-digit number `x`, `Math.log10(x).to_i + 1` runs in 0.000013s on my machine; `x.to_s.length` takes 45.9s (and I'm not willing to try `x.digits.count`).

Answer (score 4):

Although the top-voted loop is nice, it isn't very Ruby and will be slow for large numbers, the .to_s is a built-in function and therefore will be much faster. ALMOST universally built-in functions will be far faster than constructed loops or iterators.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
def ndigits(n)
  n=n.abs
  (1..1.0/0).each { |i| return i if (n /= 10).zero? }
end

ndigits(1234) # => 4
ndigits(0)    # => 1
ndigits(-123) # => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex, you can use this method:

```
def self.is_number(string_to_test)
is_number = false
# use to_f to handle float value and to_i for int
string_to_compare = string_to_test.to_i.to_s
string_to_compare_handle_end = string_to_test.to_i

# string has to be the same
if(string_to_compare == string_to_test)
  is_number = true
end
# length for fixnum in ruby
size = Math.log10(string_to_compare_handle_end).to_i + 1
# size has to be the same
if(size != string_to_test.length)
  is_number = false
end
is_number
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get fancy, you could do as simple as this.

```
def l(input)
  output = 1
  while input - (10**output) > 0
    output += 1
  end
  return output
end
puts l(456)
```

Answer (score -2):

It can be a solution to find out the length/count/size of a fixnum.

```
irb(main):004:0> x = 2021
=> 2021
irb(main):005:0> puts x.to_s.length
4
=> nil
irb(main):006:0>
```

Comment: The question is explicit about looking for a solution that _doesn't_ involve converting to a string.