# Error when printing string.length

Tags: ruby, string, fixnum

Why can't I print  the length of a constant string?
This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
Name = "Edgar Wallace"
name = "123456"

puts "Hello, my name is " + Name
puts "My name has " + Name.to_s.length + " characters."
```

I've already read "[How do I determine the length of a Fixnum in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005524/how-do-i-determine-the-length-of-a-fixnum-in-ruby)", but unfortunately it didn't help me.

After trying, this error is thrown:

```
./hello.rb:7:in `+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)
          from ./hello.rb:7:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Variables should be lowercase in Ruby, i.e. `name` instead of `Name`.

Comment: This might be a good lesson on how to interpolate strings in idiomatic ruby.  I'm sure there a lot of languages where people are expected to build strings by adding substrings but ruby is definitely not one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use  interpolation `"#{}"` in  Ruby. It will evaluate your expression and print  your string:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
Name = "Edgar Wallace"
name = "123456"

puts "My name has #{Name.length} characters."
```

Note: You can not use interpolation if you are using a string with single quotes('). Use it with double quotes.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot concatenate to a String with a Fixnum:

```
>> "A" + 1
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String
    from (irb):1:in `+'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
>> "A" + 1.to_s
=> "A1"
```

And, you don't need `Name.to_s`, because Name is already a String object. Just `Name` is enough.

Convert the Fixnum (`length`) to String:

```
puts "My name has " + Name.length.to_s + " characters."
```

Or, as an alternative:

```
puts "My name has #{Name.length} characters."
```